# Cannot add or remove packages; Errors were encountered while processing: libbz2-1.0 libbz2-1.0:i386

Tags: 12.04, package-management, aptitude, synaptics

I noticed Ubuntu had not asked me to update in a while, which is strange. So, I opened the update manager and received the message,

```
Software index is broken

It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the package manager
"Synaptic" or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a terminal to fix this issue at first.
```

So, I started a Terminal session and typed "sudo apt-get install -f". Here is the error message I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk1.0-0:i386 libffmpegthumbnailer4 efibootmgr eom-common
  libxcb-dri2-0 linux-headers-3.2.0-45 mate-media-common
  beat-hazard-ultra-bin:i386 mate-screensaver-common ffmpegthumbnailer
  python-gtksourceview2 libcairo2:i386 pidgin-data
  linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 pluma-common
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libmatewnck-common pluma libxft2:i386
  libxrandr-ltsq2 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic language-pack-kde-en
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23 kde-l10n-engb libjasper1:i386
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf indicator-status-provider-pidgin
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libpango1.0-0:i386 libmatewnck
  libxcb-render0:i386 mate-utils-common libgxps2 libxcb-shm0:i386
  language-pack-kde-en-base libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgtksourceview2.0-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libbz2-1.0:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 115 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libbz2-1.0
```

I think the problem is from when I tried to install libbz2-1.0 manually and accidentally used the i386 binary instead of the amd64 one. Can someone please help me fix this? I cannot install or remove anything until this is fixed, and really don't want to have to reinstall. Thank you for any help at all that you can give me.

Comment: Can you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt-get install -f`, and then also `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove unused dependencies (unless you need one of them. Review the list before removing).

Comment: All of these commands error out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out how to fix it myself. For anyone else who gets this problem, here is what you need to do:

1. Type `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. It will error out, but don't worry.
2. Find the files causing the problems and type `sudo dpkg -r PACKAGE_NAME` for each one to remove it. Some of them will fail to be removed. Add them to a list.
3. Run `sudo dpkg --configure PACKAGE_NAME` for each package in your list. It will configure them. This time, you should not see any errors.
4. Run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies.
5. Profit!

Comment: I just had a similar problem again, and this worked a second time. It seems that this method is reliable for fixing "Software Index is Broken"-related problems.